# Managing View outlets in ios 5.0 and ios 6.0

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios6, didreceivememorywarning, viewdidunload

I am working on an iPad application which is converted to ARC. Application is for os >= ios 5.0. So my doubt is that, how do I manage viewOutlets?  I use -(void)didReceivememoryWarning to set ViewOutlets to nil. But in ios 5.0 and 5.1 application shows lots of memory leaks. As -(void)viewDidUnload is deprecated in ios 6.0 , I am not using the same in the application. Is the correct way to manage outlets? Please give me a quick reply.

Answer (score 2):

ARC (automatic reference counting) features is available in iOS 5 and ahead (iOS 6 and so on..) version.

```
When you are using ARC unable in your project, you dont need to `manually release any object` that you have allocated for your stuff.

ARC will automatic handle this one.so it will beneficial for `Memory Management`.


Hope ,You understand what i m trying to say.
```

for more clarification , please refer below link:
   [To ARC or not to ARC? What are the pros and cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760431/to-arc-or-not-to-arc-what-are-the-pros-and-cons)
   [ARC, worth it or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876415/arc-worth-it-or-not)

```
Good Luck !!!
```

Answer (score 0):

There is NO DIFFERENCE in how you code for iOS 5 vs. iOS 6.

If you are having problems, it's because you don't understand what `viewDidUnload` does and when it's called.

`viewDidUnload` is called when the view of the controller is unloaded. In iOS 6, views are never unloaded. *In iOS 5 and before, views were almost never unloaded either*. So in both cases, pretty much `viewDidUnload` is never called.

If your program is leaking stuff, it's because you are not releasing things. You always need to release instance variables in `dealloc`. I suspect that this is your problem.

When the controller's view is unloaded (which only happens in iOS 5 and before, but this is irrelevant), `viewDidUnload` allows you to optionally discard some resources to save memory, as long as they are resources that will be re-created when the view is loaded again. This usually includes properties and instance variables that are outlets (since when the view is loaded, it will load the Xib again and re-connect the outlets to new objects), as well as any variables that are set in `viewDidLoad`.

If you coded your program correctly, I can go in there and remove `viewDidUnload`, and it would not have any effect on the correctness of the program. (Since `viewDidUnload` is almost never called anyway.)

You should almost never have to use `didReceiveMemoryWarning` either.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you please tell me about the releasing stuffs in ARC based application. I went through some articles, but did not get any idea about how to release objects in ARC project. I am setting all View outlets to nil. But this does not make any big change. My application still crashes after showing memory warning.