# How to refrain from retaining target of NSTimer in NON-ARC code.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, nstimer

I'm not using `ARC` so I can't use weak.
Please let me know, that what can I do to not allow the **NSTimer** to retain the target which in my case is self.

Comment: Why don't you want the timer to retain its target? Show your relevant code and explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754827/how-to-zeroing-weak-references-under-non-arc

Comment: unsafe_unretained. But why are you not using arc and why do you want to do what you describe in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might just go ahead and create a version of NSTimer that does not retain its target

```
+ (NSTimer *) scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)ti target:(id)aTarget selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)yesOrNo
{
    NSWeakTimerTarget* timerTarget = [[NSWeakTimerTarget alloc] init];
    timerTarget.target = aTarget;
    timerTarget.selector = aSelector;
    timerTarget.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:ti target:timerTarget selector:@selector(fire) userInfo:userInfo repeats:yesOrNo];
    return timerTarget.timer;
}
```

from https://gist.github.com/bendytree/5674709

Comment: There are several things not to like with that gist. The most obvious one is evading one of Apple’s class prefixes—especially not NS. Honestly: **DO NOT DO THAT!** Ever. The rest is too long to fit this narrow comment box. I’ll post an answer later on.

Comment: please add an answer with the details