# Are there any concrete study of the performance impact of using ARC?

Tags: objective-c, performance, automatic-ref-counting

I could not find an objective study regarding ARC performance impact in a real life project.  [The official doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) says

> The compiler efficiently eliminates many extraneous retain/release calls and much effort has been invested in speeding up the Objective-C runtime in general. In particular, the common “return a retain/autoreleased object” pattern is much faster and does not actually put the object into the autorelease pool, when the caller of the method is ARC code.

which has been relayed/deformed by tech-fanboys into  "ARC is faster".

What I know for sure is what I measured. We recently migrated our iOS project to ARC and I did some performance measurement before/after on some CPU intensive area of our code (production code, compiled with the `-Os` flag, of course).

I observed a 70% (yes 70%) performance regression.  Using *Instruments* to track retain/release events, I realized that the compiler introduces a LOT of retain/release pairs in area where you would not do it (in pre ARC environment). Basically, any temporary becomes strong.  That is, I believe, the source of the performance regression.

The original code, before the migration, was already quite optimized.  There was barely any autorelease done.  Hence, there was little room for improvement by switching to ARC.

Fortunately, *Instruments* was able to show me the most costly retain/released introduced by ARC and I was able to deactivate them using __unsafe_unretained.  This slightly mitigates the performance regression.

Does anybody have any information on this or other technique to avoid the performance loss ?  (apart from deactivating ARC)

Thanks.

EDIT:
I'm not saying that ARC is bad because of the performance impact.  The advantage of using ARC are largely superior than the performance regression (In our code, the regression did not have any visible effect, so I let it go). I consider ARC a very good technology.  I will never go back to MRC.  I'm asking this question more by curiosity.

I'm just slightly annoyed by the vast majority of blogs  on the topic (like [here](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/articles/migrating-your-code-to-objective-c-arc/) [and there](http://maniacdev.com/ios-5-sdk-tutorial-and-guide/arc-automatic-reference-counting/)) that more or less gives the impression that ARC code are going to be faster than MRC code (something I believed before I put my hands on it).  And I really have the feeling this is not the case outside some micro benchmarks.  At best you can hope to be on par with MRC, not faster.  I made a few other simple tests involving objects manipulations (like counting word in a documents).  Every time ARC was slower (thought not as bad as the 70% perf regression I was talking initially)

\begin{sarcasm}

In fact, the aforementioned doc did answer the question:

> Is ARC slow?
>
> It depends on what you’re measuring, but generally “no.”  ...

which should obviously be understood as

\begin{parody}

> Well ... hum ... we cannot say it's slower because this is a new cool techno and we would like you to adopt it.  So we answer “no” with double quotes just to avoid a class action.  And stop asking stupid questions.

\end{parody}

\end{sarcasm}

Comment: Automatic optimization will never be as efficient as manual optimization. Also, ARC is crap (not just because of this, it is crap in general).

Comment: @H2CO3 i Don't think that ARC is crap ... It is only your opinion, I rather think that is a huge effort to manage memory in simpler/better way and it is a bleeding edge compiler technology that can replace a GC ...

Comment: ARC sure saves me a lot of typing. How is it crap?

Comment: @H2CO3 you're really not a fan of ARC, are you ;-) Do you have a blog post or anywhere where you spell out your reasons? I'd be very interested to see them. I regularly switch between ARC and MRC codebases and _far_ prefer ARC.

Comment: @jrturton no I'm not, certainly :) I haven't such a paper at hand but there is a lot of discussion about ARC vs MRC, and your suggestion really makes me think that I should explain and back my opinion with facts, I think I'll do it soon.

Comment: Have you blogged yet? If so, we could go head to head. I'll be doing an ARC/MRC performance comparison once and for all. I already debunked ARC myths http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/06/mythbusting-8-reasons-arc/ and what you need to know about it http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/11/everything-know-about-arc/
There's probably less than 1% of code in any app that would benefit from hand-tuned MRC code, and for those areas you can just disable ARC in a single file. No reason to go masochist on yourself for the remaining 99% due to a vague notion of performance loss.

Comment: Saving typing strikes me as a shallow reason for ARC. My strong preference towards using it is due to recognition of my own human fallibility. I've written a tremendous amount of objc code across many projects over the last ten years, and despite that, I find that I am still not able to write bug-free code reliably. ARC, backed by an understanding of MRC, and performance profiling tools (which may lead to the occasional ARC-disabled file), gets me a little closer to that ideal.

Comment: (Also, if you find cases where there's a significant slowdown in ARC that is unavoidable, I'm sure the LLVM team would appreciate a bug report. Even if it turns out to be impossible for the compiler to do the job, they can pass the bug along to frameworks teams to come up with a more optimizable idiom for that task)

Comment: ARC vs MRC benchmark results: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2013/03/confirmed-arc-slow/

Answer (score 6):

Here are my [ARC vs MRC performance measurements](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2013/03/confirmed-arc-slow/). The performance test project is [available on github](https://github.com/LearnCocos2D/LearnCocos2D/tree/master/Cocos2D-ARC-Performance-Test) so you can add your own tests. Just be sure to run it on a device. The results in the Simulator are skewed, and often in favor of MRC.

To summarize:

**ARC and MRC are generally the same speed**. In general code should be faster under ARC, but tight loops can be slower and significantly so.

In low-level tests ARC has an edge over MRC speed-wise, due to optimizations (autorelease returns, @autoreleasepool).

There is some code where ARC inserts additional retain/release that would not strictly be necessary under MRC, as long as the app is single-threaded. Such code may be slower under ARC, though it only makes a difference in tight loops and depends a lot on the code in question.

For example a method receiving an object should retain it even under MRC, because it might be released in a multithreaded application while the method is running. The fact that you can omit that code in MRC makes it faster, but inherently unsafer (although you'll rarely run into such an issue, OTOH if you do you wish you hadn't). Example:

```
-(void) someMethod:(id)object
{
    [object retain]; // inserted by ARC, good practice under MRC
    [object doSomething];
    [object doAnotherThing];
    [object release]; // inserted by ARC, good practice under MRC
}
```

The genetic algorithm I used in the test project is **roughly 40% slower with ARC** because of this. It is a bad (extreme) example because for an algorithm of that kind you should see far greater performance improvements by rewriting critical code sections in C due to lots of insert/remove operations on NSMutableArray, and NSNumber objects being created.

**It is downright negligent to dismiss ARC entirely because it *can* be slower** in some situations. If you find those situations to be performance critical then `-fno-objc-arc` that code or rewrite it in C.

ARC should not be considered for or against because of performance considerations. [ARC is a tool that make's a programmer's job a lot easier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8760820/201863). It's up to you to decide whether you like wasting time trying to find leaked objects and dangling pointer crashes so much that you'd rather stick to MRC.

Comment: Yes, it's not online yet. Didn't expect anyone to come here so fast. :)  Give it another 10 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.  I read your post and quickly browse your sources.  Unless I miss something, your tests mostly consist on micro benchmarks (measuring low level language features).  Do you have any test that really compute some interesting stuff and are faster with ARC (apart from the genetic algo that illustrates the converse of your thesis (and I agree C would be better for those things)) ? Say differently, you take a real life source code, convert it to ARC with XCode's script and obtain something faster.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D, I disagree that your example `-someMethod:` requires those retains and releases to be safe in the presence of threads. It is an error for the caller to call a method with an object it hasn't taken responsibility to keep alive for the duration. Also, the supposed remedy of retaining and releasing in the method doesn't solve any threading issue. If the object could be deallocated between `-doSomething` and `-doAnotherThing`, then it could be deallocated before the `-retain` at the top of the method.

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you get a similar performance regression the only possible explanation is that your manual managed code was "unsafe", i mean there were potential memory leaks and less retain/release calls that made the program memory management in some way unsafe .

I don't think that ARC code is so slower than manually managed one, if the manually managed is well written and safe ...

Of course I think too that a manually managed code well written could be slightly faster than an ARC one, but at what cost ? A lot more work to do by hand ...  **In most cases it is more trouble than it is worth !**

In addition, I think that ARC should be compared with a Garbage Collector environment and not with a *perfect written MRC*, *a man brain will ever be smarter than a program (or at least I hope so ... :-) )* ...

However if you have a well written MRC code base and you are really sure that is safe and faster, why put it under ARC ? Keep it manually memory managed, using `-fno-objc-arc` flag ... Using ARC is not mandatory especially for these kind of reasons .

Comment: Well, I doubt this be the reason. OP seems much more intelligent than having written bad production code...

Comment: @H2CO3 See my edited answer ... You should not compare ARC with perfect MRC, but rather with a GC environment ...

Comment: The pre-ARK code was ok.  It did not leak nor crashed. Of course, it contained far less retain/release pair  compare to what the ARC compiler generates.  But I knew the corresponding values could not be released from under my feet.  This information comes from the global knowledge of the object graph (which is inaccessible to the ARC compiler).  So that does not make my old pre-ARC code unsafe.  I agree with you on the merits of ARC and I don't plan to revert the switch.  I just regret that few information is available on the performance impact (that I'm ok to pay)

Comment: @aleroot: the initial question is "Does anybody have any information on this or other technique to avoid the performance loss ? (apart from deactivating ARC)". Any real answer to that question?

Answer (score 1):

The cases where you possibly get a noticeable performance regression is where you send messages or call C/C++ functions having object parameters and where the number of instructions is relatively small per such function. The compiler will insert (and later not optimize away again) a retain/release pair for each parameter.

Considering the context, the compiler may recognize that certain retain/release pairs are unnecessary. However I've noticed, that even if a function is called which is declared static inline and which resides in the same translation unit as the caller, the compiler won't be able to optimize away unnecessary pairs of retain/release calls for the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid to talk something out of topic, and also based on guess...

---

I think most of performance gain from ARC is by inlining retain/release calls rather than eliding them.

Also, as far as I experienced, ARC usually introduces extra retain/release call. Because ARC is very strict and conservative, so it mostly doesn't perform retain/release elision. And many of newly inserted retain/release calls are semantically required, but omitted by programmer under MRC. (For example, all the passing-in function parameters and temporary variables)

So,

1. Count of calls to retain/release actually increased *a lot* to satisfy semantic completeness strictly.
2. A few of them will be elided by very conservative *optimization*.
3. Actual calls to retain/release will be inlined by optimization - by becoming static C function call from dynamic Objective-C method invoke - so calling cost itself will be reduced a lot.

As a result, we usually get decreased performance. I realized I was omitting a lot of retain/release calls before using ARC. But as you pointed, whatever we get, it's semantically *complete*, and still can be *manually* - so deterministic - elided by using `__unsafe_unretained`.

Answer (score 0):

***Of course*** temporary variables are strong be default.  That's explicit and clearly documented. And, if you think things through, it's what people will typically want.

```
 MyWidget *widget=[[MyWidget alloc]init];  // 1
 [myWidget mill]; // 2
```

If widget isn't strong, the new MyWidget will be created in line 1 and can be released and zeroed before line 2!

Now, it's certainly true that if you use lots of temporary variables -- for example, if you are rigorously obeying the Law of Demeter -- in the middle of a tight loop, and if you're assuming that those temporary variables have no performance cost at all because the world has plenty of registers, then you're going to be surprised.

And that might be the corner you're inhabiting right now.

But that's an exotic and special place!  Most code isn't in the middle of a tight loop. Most tight loops aren't performance bottlenecks.  And most tight loops don't need lots of intermediate variables.

Conversely, ARC can do the autorelease optimization in ways that you can't do manually (though perhaps the optimizer can).  So, if there's a function returning an autoreleased variable in your tight loop, you may be better off with ARC.

**Premature optimization is a bad idea.** You may be in an inescapable performance corner, but most people are not. I spend most of my time in OS X, to be sure, but it's been years since I've had a performance issue where the answer wasn't a better algorithm.

(Finally, if ARC is causing a 70% performance hit to your application, then you're doing an awful lot of memory management on your critical path!  Think about that: you're spending 70% of your time allocating and releasing objects. This sounds like a textbook case for something like a Flyweight or an object cache or a recycling pool!)

Comment: correction, this is 70% of time retaining and releasing, not allocating. So pools or object caches would not change anything (in fact, there is already a pool.  And this is in the pool management that the compiler inserts so many useless retain/release pair!)

Comment: I didn't mean the autorelease pool -- I was thinking of the familiar idiom where, instead of allocating objects and freeing them when you're done, you keep "unused" objects for recycling. See NSTableView, for example.

Comment: It's hard to imagine that you're spending THAT MUCH time just retaining and releasing without allocation or freeing. What else are you doing inside your critical section?  Is there a concurrency issue here?  I'm having a hard time figuring why a retain/release pair that doesn't allocate or deallocate would require much more overhead than a couple of dispatches and an increment/decrement pair.

Comment: @MarkBernstein: Increments and decrements are the main reason why reference counting is so slow. They often cause cache misses.