# Analyzing memory leaks in Xcode 5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks

I'm still a newb to objective C and Xcode 5. I have made a simple game and was performing some analysis on the game's memory leaks using one of Xcode's built in performance tools (Cmd+I). To make the game I was using cocos2D framework.

Now it looks like I had quite a few memory leaks (screenshot below). A few things I wanted to address were (keep in mind it's a really small game)

- Are the memory leaks being shown significant? Or is it normal to have a few memory leaks in the bytes-kbytes range?
- Many of them are "Malloc -" and have no trace in the Extended Detail view. How do you deal with these?
- I know Xcode has the option to turn on Objective-C ARC. Would it be a better idea for me to just turn that on instead of worrying about keeping track of memory leaks and all of that? (keep in mind I'm a newb)

Thanks, here's the screenshot!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the more important thing about memory leaks is how often does it occur. If it happens on app load once, i don't think it will matter that much, but if it happens in a loop or after every user action then I think it is something to be worried about.

And I definitely recommend using ARC, that question has been posted to SO many times, here you can find better answers than I could ever give.

[ARC, worth it or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876415/arc-worth-it-or-not)

[To ARC or not to ARC? What are the pros and cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760431/to-arc-or-not-to-arc-what-are-the-pros-and-cons)

[To use Automatic Reference Counting or not to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048398/to-use-automatic-reference-counting-or-not-to-use)