# Memory leak in image

Tags: objective-c, memory, uiimage, memory-leaks

I'm using the profiler in xcode 4 to determinate if I have any memory leaks. I didn't have this leak before, but with xcode 5 I have this one.

I'm trying to set an image for the tab item of my `UIViewController and the profiler marks this line :

```
    image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imgPath];   <<=== Leak : 9.1%
```

This is part of my code I don't understand why. What's the best way to resolve this issue?

```
    NSString *imgPath;
    UIImage *image;

    IBNewsViewController *newsView = [[IBNewsViewController alloc] initWithURL:[tvLocal urlFlux] title:@"News" isEmission:NO];
    [newsView setTitle:@"News"];
    imgPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:"news" ofType:@"png"];
    image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imgPath];   <<=== Leak : 9.1%
    newsView.tabBarItem.image = image;
    [image release];
    image = nil;
    UINavigationController* navNew = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newsView];
    [newsView release];
    newsView = nil;
```

EDIT:
No leak on iOS6.

Why it's leak on iOS7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should switch to the autoreleasing `imageNamed:` method. This has the added benefit of system level cacheing of the image.

```
NSString *imgPath;
UIImage *image;

IBNewsViewController *newsView = [[IBNewsViewController alloc] initWithURL:[tvLocal urlFlux] title:@"News" isEmission:NO];
[newsView setTitle:@"News"];

image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"news"];   
newsView.tabBarItem.image = image;

UINavigationController* navNew = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newsView];
[newsView release];
newsView = nil;
```

To make life easier on yourself I'd switch your project to use ARC so you have less to worry about WRT memory management.

Comment: i am using Arc and i get some leaks for [imageview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img-568h@2x"]]; only in simulator for now

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imgPath];
```

With

```
image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imgPath];
```

and check once.

Answer (score 0):

First, [switch to ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760431/to-arc-or-not-to-arc-what-are-the-pros-and-cons). There is no single thing you can do on iOS that will more improve your code and remove whole classes of memory problems with a single move.

Beyond that, the code above does not appear to have a leak itself. That suggests that the actual mistake is elsewhere. There are several ways this could happen:

- You're leaking the `IBNewsViewController` somewhere else
- `IBNewsViewController` messes with its `tabBarItem` incorrectly and leaks that
- You're leaking the `UINavigationController` somewhere else
- You're retaining the `tabBarItem.image` somewhere else and failing to release it

Those are the most likely that I would hunt for. If you're directly accessing ivars, that can often cause these kinds of mistakes. You should use accessors everywhere except in `init` and `dealloc`. (This is true in ARC, but is absolutely critical without ARC.)

Leak detection is not perfect. There are all kinds of "abandoned" memory that may not appear to be a leak. I often recommend using [Heapshot](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/) (now "Generation") analysis to see what other objects may be abandoned; that may give you a better insight into this leak.

Why differences in iOS 6 vs iOS 7? I suspect you have the same problem on iOS 6, but it doesn't look like a "leak", possibly because there is something caching the image that was removed in iOS 7. The cache pointer may make it look like it's not a leak to Instruments.

Speaking of which, do make sure to run the static analyzer. It can help you find problems.

And of course, switch to ARC.