# Potential memory leak - Received Memory Warning

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

I am using iOS 7 and I am getting memory warnings in this part of code, but I'am not able to understand how the retain count increases as I release imageToSave variable too.

[image: This is image of code when i analyze my code]

Comment: This is not quite an answer, but why are you not using ARC?

Comment: Are `finalOutput:` return autoreleased object? By naming convention it should be autoreleased. If not, then method should be named `createFinalOutput:`

Comment: because i started it writing in ios 6 as there was option of choosing or not choosing arc ,i didn't choose that time ,as you all know ,that time we all need more time to understand arc :-)

Comment: @Cy-4AH sorry to ask but what difference will going to be by changing name of method ?

Comment: I second @StefanFisk. I wonder why people still go the hard way of manual memory management.

Comment: @Isuru Because it gives you more control over ARC and way better memory management then ARC

Comment: I've never seen an example of when non-ARC code performs better than ARC code. Apple has also stated several times that ARC code will have its retain/release calls optimized by the compiler, so that unnecessary calls are removed completely.

Comment: @StefanFisk read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760431/to-arc-or-not-to-arc-what-are-the-pros-and-cons

Comment: read it, but I can't find any mention of better memory management, only the possibility of doing odd stuff like ids in structs without cumbersome casts.

Comment: @kshitijgodara, it's just naming convention that object returned by methods, started with `copy`, `create`, `new`, `int`, should be released. In other cases object is already autoreleased. By this convention and looking at yours code, you don't need release imageToSave.

Comment: @StefanFisk,@Isuru,@Retro - Guys nyc conversation ,when such great mind discuss things out,every feel obliged by getting shower of knowledge .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static analyser not always write about memory leak but its assuming that when you are calling `finalOutput` its returning you an allocated object mean +1 retain count object which is never used and its treating this waring as memory leak!

Comment: so how do i stop this warning , Am i not using final output ?

Comment: just remove the [imageToSave release] from your code because you have not allocated it!

Answer (score 1):

You have not allocated memory to this object yourself, so you don't own it. And you are still releasing it.You can't release objects you don't own.
Unless you use alloc method to allocate memory, you can't just release them........