# Python: logging the garbage collector

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I have a python application that has some performance hiccups. I want to add the garbage collector's events (especially, when does it get called) to my logs. Is it possible?

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html#gc.set_debug

You can set the Flags, but they get written to stderr.

Available flags are

```
gc.DEBUG_STATS
gc.DEBUG_COLLECTABLE
gc.DEBUG_UNCOLLECTABLE
gc.DEBUG_INSTANCES
gc.DEBUG_OBJECTS
gc.DEBUG_SAVEALL
gc.DEBUG_LEAK
```

**ALSO**

When you are dealing with performance, you might wish to profile your code for exhaustive Loops or Function calls. You can use `cProfile` or `hotshot`. More here http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html

Comment: thanks for the performance tip, but my application has those hiccups in sporadic places, that usually don't involve loops or recursion. That's why I suspect the GC

Answer (score 1):

Python (at least CPython version 2.x) uses reference counting to implement its garbage collector (cf. [Why Java and Python garbage collection methods are different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21934/why-java-and-python-garbage-collection-methods-are-different)), so it's not really "called", as it is in Java.

`Refcounting` means that each time a new reference to a given object is created, a counter is incremented, each time the reference is lost (end of scope, reassignment, ...), the counter is decremented. When it reaches 0, the object memory is freed.

<del>So the solution Python offers to your problem is to override the `__del__` method of the object:</del>

```
class test:
    def __del__(self):
         #self is about to be freed, do what ever you want 
         pass
```

**EDIT:**
According to the link above, there is another mechanism running periodically:

> CPython (reference counting is not part of python itself, but part of the C implementation thereof) catches circular references with a separate garbage collection routine that it runs periodically...

but only involved in case of circular references.

**EDIT 2:**
As mentioned in the comments and [here](http://excess.org/article/2011/12/unfortunate-python/#__del__), `__del__` is not the safest solution. Here is a certainly better way to achieve a similar behavior:

```
import weakref

class test:
    pass

t = test()

def prepare_cb(obj):
  #save information about the obj
  uid = id(obj)

  def do_some_logging(weak):
     print "Object %s cleaned up" % uid

  return do_some_logging

weak = weakref.ref(t, prepare_cb(t))

del t
```

Comment: This will only work for the custom classes and not for the built-ins. Also, "ALL" the classes in the source code will have to be edited.

Comment: The GC module only deals with cyclic references. Defining `__del__` is a actually a terrible idea because it makes the object uncollectable by the cyclic GC.

Comment: @gnibbler: good point, the [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html#gc.garbage) is clear about that. So it depends how frequent are the cyclic refs in the code, and what you actually want to know about garbage collection.